# VBA compile error object required

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have inherited a vba project and have been recently getting my feet wet with vba development. I have enountered an error `Compile Error Object Required` when running a portion of code that I have recently made edits to. Since it's a compile error, I cant see at runtime exactly which line is throwing the error. The only code I have modified is the `ElseIf` block in the following code... all help is appreciated.

```
            If tableType = 1 Then 'Resident/Local
                Set db = CurrentDb
                db.Execute "ALTER TABLE [" & TableName & "] ALTER COLUMN [" & KeyColumn & "] COUNTER(1,1)"
            ElseIf tableType = 4 Then
                Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
                Dim connectionString As String
                Set connectionString = DLookup("[Connect]", "[MSysObjects]", "[Name] = '" & TableName & "'")
                conn.connectionString = connectionString
                conn.Open
                Dim cmd As ABODB.Command
                Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
                cmd.ActiveConnection = conn
                cmd.CommandText = "ALTER TABLE [" & TableName & "] ALTER COLUMN [" & KeyColumn & "] COUNTER(1,1)"
                cmd.Execute
                conn.Close
            Else 'Linked Table
                Set wsp = DBEngine.Workspaces(0)
                Set db = wsp.OpenDatabase(DLookup("[Database]", "[MSysObjects]", "[Name] = '" & TableName & "'"))
                db.Execute "ALTER TABLE [" & TableName & "] ALTER COLUMN [" & KeyColumn & "] COUNTER(1,1)"  'reset the autonumber column value
            End If
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the `Set` from this line:

```
Set connectionString = DLookup("[Connect]", "[MSysObjects]", "[Name] = '" & TableName & "'")
```

`Set` is only used for assigning object references, and `connectionString` is a `String`.

For future reference, the VBE will highlight the line with the compile error if you use Debug->Compile from the menu.

Answer (score -1):

Normally if I was writing and if statement o would have it like this

```
If tableType = 1 Then 'Resident/Local
            Set db = CurrentDb
            db.Execute "ALTER TABLE [" & TableName & "] ALTER COLUMN [" & KeyColumn & "] COUNTER(1,1)"
        Else
If tableType = 4 Then
```

give that a bash. May just bee the formatting error

Comment: There is no "formatting" (syntax?) error in OP's code other than incorrect usage of the `Set` keyword to assign a string.  Also, using nested `If/Else/If`` statements instead of an `ElseIf` makes for unnecessarily complicated/nested `If` blocks and hampers readability and maintainability (spaghetti code)